# Why are links to Mysites reverting to http?

Tags: central-administration, mysites

I have been working on mysites within my Sp2016 environment recently.

I have my bindings and ports to http/https set up in IIS.

I have AAM set up (http as default, https as Intranet).

My site host location is http://mysite.xxxxxxxx.co.uk:80/

I have URL rewrite set up via IIS (to direct to https).

The initial mysite set up was created before I was assigned the project, but I have done all of the above.

Whats happening -
When I search for a person, their profile picture is trying to hit **http** and doesnt display - the hyperlink of their name is going to **https** and works.

When testing on a page, with a newsfeed....

Profile pic and hyperlink for myself are correctly going to **https**.
For other users in the 'conversation', profile pic and hyperlink to **http** (profile picture displays though).

I appreciate this all sounds a bit screwy (I'm struggling to get my head round it, hence why I am here). I would be grateful for any pointers on cause, and if possible any tips on how to resolve.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried an AAM setting for your mysites - specifically https://mysite.xxx.co.uk

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.

In AAM, I have:

http://mysite.xxx.co.uk set as default (http) / 
https://mysite.xxx.co.uk set as Intranet (https)